# Renaming a file upon copy-item

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm currently reading a CSV file and creating a folder structure dependent on column values and copying files into these sub-directories. I'm currently struggling to adjust this, so that the file name is amended upon the copy to `DotDate_CurrentName` (`DotDate` is a column in the csv).

```
##Pull the CSV & Create Directories
Echo "Getting root directory for CSV File" #via root variable

#import the csv file and loop through the results
Echo "Importing CSV file"
Import-Csv -Path "$($FilePath)\$($DateStr)_$($TimeStr)_Export.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    Echo "Building subpath and fullpath strings"
    $subPath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($_.'ID' + '_' + $_.'First Name' + '_' + $_.'Surname', $_.Area, $_.SubArea, $_.'DotDate')
    $fullPath = Join-Path -Path $rootPath -ChildPath $subPath
    "Test fullpath and build path from strings"
    if (!(Test-Path -Path $fullPath -PathType Container)) {
        New-Item -Path $fullPath -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
    }
    Copy-Item -Path $_.'Document File Path' -Destination $fullPath
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 - My question is there. how do I adjust this, so that the file name is amended upon the copy to DotDate_CurrentName (DotDate is a column in the csv).

Comment: Where exactly?  Your question is still ambiguous.  You're already using `$_.DotDate` in your code.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 There is only one copy-item taking place, and this is at the end of the snippet above. As of now, the copy is taking the file and copying this to the new location, with the same name. I'd like this to copy the file and rename it, to append the $_.DotDate variable to the start of the file name. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Can you add some example data from your .csv into your question? What are the values of `$subPath` and `$fullPath` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to copy then rename; you can do both in the same action.  To prepend the `DotDate`, you can do something like this:

```
#requires -Version 4
@(Import-Csv -Path "$FilePath${DateStr}_${TimeStr}_Export.csv").ForEach{
    $path = [IO.Path]::Combine(
        $rootPath,
        ('{0}_{1}_{2}' -f $_.ID, $_.'First Name', $_.Surname),
        $_.Area,
        $_.SubArea,
        $_.DotDate
    )

    if (-not (Test-Path -Path $path -PathType Container)) {
        New-Item -Path $path -ItemType Directory >$null
    }

    $copy = [IO.FileInfo]$_.'Document File Path'
    $copy | Copy-Item -Destination "$path\$($_.DotDate)_$($copy.Name)"
}
```